# Show this inequality in the "heat equation" problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Let $(u,t)$ the $C^2$ solution of the equation 
>   $$
> u_t=u_{xx}+u, \textrm{ over } [0,a]\times[0,T]\subset \mathbb{R}^2
> $$
>   where $T>0$
>
> Show that 
>   $$
> \max\limits_{[0,a]\times[0,T]} |u| \leq e^T\max\limits_{\gamma}|u|
> $$
>   where $\gamma\dot{=}(\{0\}\times\{[0,T]\})\cup (\{a\}\times[0,T])\cup([0,a]\times\{0\})$.

This is a question of my homework in PDE.

**What I have to work**: Solutions of the "traditional" heat equations with boundary condition, the dirichlet problem, Green's identities, divergence theorem, Hölder inequality...

**My answer**:  I did some exercises of the heat equation but none is like this... I'm not knowing how to start that.

[UPDATE] **My attempt**:

$$
u=u_t-u_{xx}\Rightarrow u=\varphi(x)G(t)
$$
so
$$
u_t=G_t(t)\varphi(x) \textrm{ and } u_xx=G(t)\varphi_{xx}(x) \Rightarrow \varphi(x)G(t)=G_t(t)\varphi(x)-G(t)\varphi_{xx}(x)\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 1=\frac{1}{G(t)}G_t(t)-\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\varphi_{xx}(x)\Rightarrow\left(1+\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\varphi_{xx}(x)\right)=\frac{1}{G(t)}G_t(t)=\lambda
$$
where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary positive constant. What I have is this:

$$
\frac{1}{G(t)}G_t(t)=\lambda
$$
and
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\varphi_{xx}(x)\right)=\lambda
$$

So, for the first equation, $G(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ and supposing that we have that $u=\varphi(x)e^{\lambda t}$. But this implies that $u_{xx}=0$ (*and this not make sense for me*).

Furthermore, if I try solve this by the maximum principle, as $T>0$ and $e^T\geq 1$
$$
\max\limits_{[0,a]\times[0,T]} |u|=\max\limits_{\gamma} |u|\leq e^T\max\limits_{\gamma} |u|
$$
and so this confused me because I did not use the hypothesis $u_t=u_{xx}+u$

Comment: This is a problem in Evans, isn't it? I feel like I've done something like this before, but with hints, and I don't remember anything else.

Comment: Have you consider some sort of Grunwald inequality?

Comment: @nayrb I don't know if this is a problem in Evans, but I will verify that. Please don't consider this inequality the teacher don't explained this in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Rewrite the PDE to

$$ u = u_t - u_{xx}$$

You probably done the maximum principal (without the forcing term), so what can you say about:

$$\max_{\Omega}|u| = \max_{\Omega} | u_t - u_{xx} | \leq ?$$

Where $\Omega$ is the domain you're working in. If that doesn't help, what if you assume the solution takes the form $u(x,t)=e^t X(x)$?

Comment: The maximum principle gives me that 
$
\max\limits_{\Omega\times[0,T]}|u|$
$=\max\limits_{\Omega\times[0,T]}|u_t-u_{xx}|=\max\limits_{\gamma}|u_t-u_{xx}|.
$
But, who is $\leq$ that the last part? Must I use the triangular inequality? Can I assume that solution for $u$?

Comment: If $u(x,t)=e^tX(x)$ so $u_t=u$ and $u_{xx}=0$, this make sense?